# Call Azure function inside the Kubernetes cluster shows error?

Tags: c#, azure, kubernetes, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I Created python azure function and its working fine in the local environment and I attached a storage account. I changed authLevel as below  `"authLevel": "anonymous"`.then I created a docker image and deployed in kubernetes cluster using deployment YAML in the azurefunction namespace

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: configuration
  labels:
    app: configuration
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: configuration
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: configuration
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: configuration
        image: global.azurecr.io/config:1
        env:
        - name: AzureFunctionsJobHost__functions__0
          value: configuration
        envFrom:
        - secretRef:
            name: configuration
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: pull
```

**Kubectl create -f configuration.yaml -n azurefunction**.
also, I created a service for this azure function

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: configuration-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app:  configuration
```

**Kubectl create -f configuration-service.yaml -n azurefunction**
.I tried to call the Azure function from other namespace using c# code.

```
var postresponse = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://configuration-service:80/api/ConfigurationInfo");
```

**deployed in api namespace**
its showing an error

```
StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:
```

Comment: Hi, If you are calling from different namespace then URL hostname should have the namespace of the service. Can you please try using http://configuration-service.azurefunction:80/api/ConfigurationInfo

Comment: i tried with .namesapce url.but still got the same error not found.  thank you for mention that mistake

Comment: The app is listening on port 80 or 8080? You said it works in local. What url you used to test in local?

Comment: while running in  local environment without specifying any port (--port option) app running 7071 default port.(Now listening on: http://0.0.0.0:7071).
but when I'm running the app in kuberentes cluster it shows  Now listening on: http://[::]:80.that is the reason i put port 80.even if 7071 , shows same error not found

Comment: @Kiruba  is this correct format for different namespace option .  configuration-service.azurefunction:80/api/ConfigurationInfo